# Excel - specific cut/paste, delete pattern that needs automation

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have a macro that copies a big range of data (320 rows and 3 columns) that I need to apply the following steps to - cut row 2 and insert it before row 9 and delete row 4. Now this data range has another pattern.

[this pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJmxi.jpg)

This pattern is copied from 40 files that contain different information but structured the same way. Each of the 40 files has 8 rows that are copied(colored in different colors in the picture). I need to cut/paste and delete specific rows on each group of 8 down the line to 40 (possibly more). Here is how I do it currently.

```
    Rows("2:2").cut
    Rows("9:9").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("4:4").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("9:9").cut
    Rows("16:16").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("11:11").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("16:16").cut
    Rows("23:23").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("18:18").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("23:23").cut
    Rows("30:30").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("25:25").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("30:30").cut
    Rows("37:37").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("32:32").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("37:37").cut
    Rows("44:44").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("39:39").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("44:44").cut
    Rows("51:51").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("46:46").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("51:51").cut
    Rows("58:58").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("53:53").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("58:58").cut
    Rows("65:65").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("60:60").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("65:65").cut
    Rows("72:72").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("67:67").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("72:72").cut
    Rows("79:79").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("74:74").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("79:79").cut
    Rows("86:86").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("81:81").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("86:86").cut
    Rows("93:93").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("88:88").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("93:93").cut
    Rows("100:100").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("95:95").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("100:100").cut
    Rows("107:107").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("102:102").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("107:107").cut
    Rows("114:114").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("109:109").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("114:114").cut
    Rows("121:121").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("116:116").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("121:121").cut
    Rows("128:128").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("123:123").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("128:128").cut
    Rows("135:135").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("130:130").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("135:135").cut
    Rows("142:142").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("137:137").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("142:142").cut
    Rows("149:149").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("144:144").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("149:149").cut
    Rows("156:156").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("151:151").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("156:156").cut
    Rows("163:163").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("158:158").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("163:163").cut
    Rows("170:170").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("165:165").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("170:170").cut
    Rows("177:177").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("172:172").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("177:177").cut
    Rows("184:184").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("179:179").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("184:184").cut
    Rows("191:191").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("186:186").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("191:191").cut
    Rows("198:198").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("193:193").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("198:198").cut
    Rows("205:205").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("200:200").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("205:205").cut
    Rows("212:212").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("207:207").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("212:212").cut
    Rows("219:219").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("214:214").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("219:219").cut
    Rows("226:226").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("221:221").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("226:226").cut
    Rows("233:233").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("228:228").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("233:233").cut
    Rows("240:240").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("235:235").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("240:240").cut
    Rows("247:247").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("242:242").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("247:247").cut
    Rows("254:254").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("249:249").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("254:254").cut
    Rows("261:261").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("256:256").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("261:261").cut
    Rows("268:268").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("263:263").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("268:268").cut
    Rows("275:275").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("270:270").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("275:275").cut
    Rows("282:282").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("277:277").Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Is there a way to do this automatically by finding LastRow and not having each of these functions hardcoded as it is now? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop that increments in steps of 7

```
Sub moveRows()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow Step 7
        'Do your stuff with rows i, i+7 and i+2 here
        LastRow = LastRow - 1 'taken from Nan Avan Illai. The result won't differ but it's "cleaner" that way
    Next i
End Sub
```

When deleting lines, it can also sometimes be helpful to go backwards in (use `Step -8`) so you don't mix up the shifting line numbers. Also automating the import of the data and edit the data while importing it might be worth looking into.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for the fast response.

As for automating the import and edit I already have. I just had a problem with this part. You can see the whole macro here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132825/consolidation-macro-for-excel

Answer (score 0):

try with below code

```
Sub test()
    Dim last, i As Long
    last = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To last Step 7
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, Columns.Count)).Cut
        Range("A" & (i + 7)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range(Cells(i + 7, 1), Cells(i + 7, Columns.Count)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        last = last - 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah I forgot to decrement the last row variable. Although it's won't make any difference (probably) it's much more thorough.

Comment: After tweaking the values a bit to cut/paste/delete the rows I needed it looks like this

     `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

     For i = 2 To LastRow Step 7

        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, Columns.Count)).cut
        Range("A" & (i + 7)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range(Cells(i + 2, 1), Cells(i + 2, Columns.Count)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        LastRow = LastRow - 1
     Next i
`

This comment system is beyond me